# ffmpeg duplicates first frame

Tags: php, ffmpeg

When I create a video from series of images, it always duplicates the first frame several times, even when I choose a framerate, which is a multiple of the number of images. This is for a folder with 290 frames. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried several things, for hours.

Command is like this:

```
$cmd5 = 'cat Folder/*.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -framerate 290/10 -i - -vcodec libx264 -vf \'scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2\' Folder/out.mp4';
```

Comment: First of all, when experiencing issues with `ffmpeg` you should remove any potential complexity due to scripting. Run the command manually in cli and provide the complete console output. Also, does using the [image file demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) instead of piping from `cat` make a difference? How do you know the first frame is being duplicated? Are you actually using the ffmpeg-php wrapper as suggested by your tag?

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images#Ifyourvideodoesnotshowtheframescorrectly may be interesting/useful

Comment: this was happening to me when transcoding .APNG to .WEBM ;
i updated FFMPEG to version N-85469-gf1d80bc and the problem went away, so it may have just been a bug